# android: ¿Al presionar el botón de retroceso regresar a el anterior fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo múltiples `fragments` *[1]*,*[2]*,*[3]*, al estar en cualquiera de ellos y presionar el botón de retroceso me saca de la aplicación. Que debo hacer para que en vez de que me saque de la aplicación, regrese al `fragment` anterior. De antemano gracias.

En mi actividad principal (es un *drawer* menu) invoco el `fragment` así:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new SearchFragment()).commit();
```

En esta misma actividad tengo el método que se acciona al presionar el botón de retroceso

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Echale un ojo a los métodos de `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Comment: edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has probado para que sea más fácil detectar el problema

Comment: Amigo devjav, siempre que preguntes acostumbra agregar si se despliega un mensaje de error en el LogCat. Si te saca de la aplicación ¿Tienes algun finish()? ,¿se muestra algo en el LogCat?

Comment: @devjav te he dejado una respuesta, lo más completa posible, parte de la actividad con menu lateral que crea el mismo android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Muy bien, te pongo un ejemplo de como lo manejé eso, que yo recuerde si funcionaba y al presionar *back* me regresaba al `fragment` anterior:

En el método que permite seleccionar de los `items` dentro del `NavigationDrawer` le agregas `.addToBackStack(null)` antes del `.commit();` a cada uno de ellos, ejemplo:

```
 @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        //Este método controla los llamados a los botones del Drawer.
        // Actualiza el contenido principal sustituyendo el fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, MainScreenSubView.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new ChatView()).addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new PremiumView()).addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new AboutView()).addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                UserModel.instance().logout();
                System.exit(0);
                finish();
        }
    }
```

***NOTA: Haz caso omiso al resto del código, solo copié y pegué desde mi repo :P***

En el método `onBackPressed()` lo dejas de la siguiente manera(Está incompleto pero tal como está es funcional :P):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
             getFragmentManager().popBackStack();//No se porqué puse lo mismo O.o
        }

    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta x4mp73r, tengo una pregunta, en cada fragment no se debe poner alguna instruccion para poder regresar?. Por ejemplo de un fragment paso a otro fragment, luego presiono retroseso, deberia regresar al anterioir fragment.

Comment: Mi respuesta esta muy clara :D, lee toda y trata de asimilarla,  `.addToBackStack(null)` con eso antes del  `commit();` en cada _case_ ya  que dentro de ellos hago el llamado a los _fragments_  que dentro del Drawer son llamados _items_ y así como tengo el método _back_ funciona, ¿Has leído mi respuesta?

Comment: Por supuesto que mire tu respuesta, a lo que me preferia es que al parecer al regresar a el anterioir fragment no vuelve a inicializar es decir, no vuelve a crear la vista (no ejecuta de nuevo el onCreateView)

Comment: Pues quien sabe como lo tengas, porque mi código hace esto: Desde el _Main_ (Que lo primero que se muestra es el drawer) selecciono el item que quiero, digamos _About_, después entro al menú y clic en _Chat_, después regreso y me muestra el fragment _About_, regreso y me manda a la principal, eso es todo lo que hace mi código, no es necesario colocar en cada _fragment_como piensas, eso se agrega en  cada _case_ del _Drawer_, eso en conjunto con el método back hacen que funcione.

Comment: Tengo una app olvidada (Un proyecto fallido) en la Play Store donde uso el código que te muestro, no estoy seguro si aún funcionen los servidores de inicios de sesión pero intenta y si funciona te darás cuenta como funciona https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mx.appco.appbogado

Comment: Deacuerdo, gracias por tus repuestas.

Comment: @x4mp73r hola amigo es correcto lo que comentas del manejo del stack de fragmentos pero me deja intrigado que comenta el usuario, en determinado momento lo saca de la aplicación, me parece que elimina los fragmentos de la pila pero no llega a cerrarla, creo que debe tener algún finish() o error por ahí =|

Comment: Quien sabe Elena, a lo que entendí es que al darle "atrás" lo saca automáticamente, como cuando te sales de cualquier aplicación(WhatsApp,gmail, etc.) :\, lo digo porque eso me ocurrió a mí antes de aplicarle lo de mi respuesta ya que todos los fragments los tomaba en cuenta como una sola "ventana" por decirlo así y como no hay mas "ventanas" mas que la que contiene el drawer que solo cambia de fragment al darle "atrás" pues se sale naturalmente, pero hasta aquí no se, solo quise aportar mi granito de arena ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas agregarlo al back stack del FragmentManager

```
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SearchFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eso la mejor opción sería usar `.add` en lugar de `.replace`
lo que hace `.add` es apilarte los fragmentos y eso hace que, cuando des back se regresa al anterior, sin necesidad de hacer otro "truco"

```
MiFragment miFragment = MiFragment.newInstance();
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, miFragment, "fragment_tag") // <-
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

El backpressed se hace sobre la actividad y no sobre el fragment... así que en la actividad puedes hacer esto:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1
       mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
    else{
       finish();
    }
}
```

El método `getBackStackEntryCount()` te refresa la candidad de fragmentos que estan actualmente apilados. Entonces si la candidad de fragments en pila son más se uno se va a pasar al anterior, si ya no hay más terminará con la actividad que los esta contendiendo :D

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es sobrescribir el método `onBackPressed(){...}` de tu Activity principal o el que contendrá todos los `Fragments`, esto para al momento de presionar el botón de back tú puedas personalizar la acción que realice tu aplicación.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   //si no queda ningún fragment sale de este activity
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
     // super.onBackPressed(); 
        finish();

    } else { //si no manda al fragment anterior.
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Después a cada `Layout` tienes que agregarle un ID en su definición. Este layout es llamado por una clase Fragment1 que extiende de `Fragment`

Cuando desees abrir un nuevo `Frament` desde tu `Activity`, tendrás que agregarlo al `FragmentManager` de la siguiente forma:

```
                    //Si deseas pasar información entre Framgnets
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("Param1", Value);

        //Declaramos el nuevo Fragment que queremos abrir                       
                     FragmentManager fm  = getFragmentManager();
                     Fragment newFragment= new Fragment1();
                     newFragment.setArguments(args); //agregamos la informacion

                     //Agregamos el Fragment a la lista. content_frame es el lugar en tu Activity donde se mostrarán los framgnetes
                 fm.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
                        .commit();
```

Si quieres abrir un nuevo `Fragment` desde otro `Fragment` la cosa sigue siendo la misma, suponiendo que estas en Fragment1 y quieres abrir Fragment 2, creas tu `Layout` y tu clase para Framgnet2

```
                    Fragment newFragment = new Fragment2();                    
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //Agregamos el Fragment al BackStack
                    transaction.replace(R.id.Fragment1, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack("Fragment1");
                    transaction.commit();
```

Y con eso aseguras la navegación entre `Fragments`.

Answer (score 1):

## Patrón de navegación entre fragmentos:

Mis conclusiones sobre el tema de navegación entre fragmentos, antes de todo debes estructurar bien la profundidad de navegación, si es muy rebuscada, el usuario puede perder la orientación de navegación.

[Guia de google sobre patrón de navegación](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)
Resumiendo: En una aplicación compuesta por dos tipos de contenido `libros` y `películas` cada uno puede tener `un listado` y una `vista de detalle`, en la vista de detalle de una película podría recomendarte su libro o viceversa.

**Fragmentos disponibles:**

Acceso directo desde el menú lateral:

- Principal
- Lista libros
- Lista películas

Sin acceso directo en el menú lateral:

- Detalle libro
- Detalle película

Pongamos que la acción del usuario realiza:

```
Principal -> Listar libros -> Listar películas -> Detalle película
```

(3 retrocesos)

```
Principal -> Listar libros -> Listar películas -> Detalle película -> Detalle libro
```

(4 retrocesos)

Siguiendo el patrón que Google recomienda, cuando se muestre el detalle del libro al retroceder se situé en el listado de libros:

```
Detalle libro -> listado de libros -> principal
```

(3 retrocesos antes de los 4) Pero no ser si es lo mejor eso, ya que el usuario se puede extrañar que se le abre el listado de libros antes que el detalle de la película, si quiere listar los libros ya tiene la acción directa al menú lateral.

Para mejorar la usuabilidad de navegación a partir del último ejemplo, modificaría la pila para que solo hayan 3 retrocesos, excluyendo el listar libros.

Quedando así:

```
Principal -> Listar películas -> Detalle película -> Detalle libro
```

(3 retrocesos antes de los 4)

**El diseño de navegación:**

- El primer fragmento cargarlo con `add` así cuando es el último sale de la app.
- Crear un pila donde se guardarán los fragmentos: `addToBackStack(TAG)`
- Para obtener cuantos fragmentos hay en la pila: `getBackStackEntryCount()`
- Acción retroceder, eliminar el último fragmento de la pila: `popBackStack()`
- Eliminar la pila si el usuario usa el menú lateral para situarse al inicio.
- Prevenir la duplicación de un fragmento en la pila, se debe rescatarlo.

### Fragmento de prueba

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_ID = "param_id";
    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "param_title";
    private static final String TAG = FragmentA.class.getSimpleName();

    private int mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    public FragmentA() {
    }

    public static FragmentA newInstance(int param1, String param2) {
        FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_ID, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_ID);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    //Al rescatar de la pila necesario resaltar el menu y cambiar el texto
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(mParam1).setChecked(true);
    getActivity().setTitle(mParam2);


        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        tvLabel.setText(mParam2);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: " + mParam1 + " " + mParam2);

        return view;
    }

}
```

### Sistema de navegación

En `onNavigationItemSelected` es donde tienes que decidir que elementos del menú tiene que cargar un `fragmento` o una `activdad`

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    Fragment newFragment = null;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        newFragment = FragmentA.newInstance(id, item.getTitle().toString());
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        newFragment = FragmentB.newInstance(id, item.getTitle().toString());
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        newFragment = FragmentC.newInstance(id, item.getTitle().toString());
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        newFragment = FragmentD.newInstance(id, item.getTitle().toString());
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    if (newFragment != null) {
        openFragment(newFragment);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

### Carga de los fragmentos

La primera vez que se quiera cargar un fragmento utilizar `add` así cuando no hay más fragmentos a la pila saldrá de la app.

```
private void addFragment(Fragment newFragment) {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Para los otros fragmentos

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment) {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.commit();

}
```

**Prevenir la carga del fragmento actual en la vista**

Si identificas el `FrameLayout` con un identificador, en este caso `frame_container` con la siguiente función puedes prevenir la duplicación de cargar el fragmento:

```
private void openFragment(Fragment newFragment){
    if (!containerFragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(newFragment.getClass().getName())) {
        replaceFragment(newFragment);
    }
}
```

Englobar todo en una función tanto la carga del primer fragmento y los otros con prevención de carga de fragmento duplicado:

```
private void openFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    Fragment containerFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);

    if (containerFragment == null){
        addFragment(newFragment);
    } else{
        if (!containerFragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(newFragment.getClass().getName())) {
            replaceFragment(newFragment);
        }
    }
}
```

Si al iniciar la app quieres cargar un fragmento en concreto:

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_gallery));
```

### Computar retroceso

Para controlar la acción de retroceso con `Fragments` y teniendo en cuenta que hay un `NavigationView`el `onBackPressed` debe quedar así

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Buen trabajo, lo voy a implementar

Comment: gracias por el aporte amigo, bien explicado, implementado sin problemas, saludos

Answer (score -1):

No sé si te sirva, pero ahí va.

Yo uso Navigation Drawer Activity, en el cual implemento el siguiente método

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {//si ya no hay más naa que regresar
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.nav_home); //coloca el nombre base al bar
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Ahora te explico:

1. Hago un try catch para cualquier posible error que pueda o no surgir
2. Verifico si ya no hay más fragmentos que regresar, esto para devolver el nombre del fragmento original en el action bar
3. Llamo al popBackStack para que regrese según la pila de fragmentos

Luego en los fragmentos excepto el principal que es el nav_home, coloco el nombre en el action bar con la siguiente línea

```
//coloca el titulo en acction bar
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.log_out);
```

Con esto debería funcionarte, yo lo hago así, sencillo y rápido.

Espero les sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.