# Controlar la cantidad de botón atrás en Android - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, back-button

Tengo una aplicación móvil de turismo y mi problema radica en que un sitio puede tener sub-sitios y a su vez cada actividad tiene varios fragmentos. Entonces cuando me quiero retroceder para salirme o regresar a la principal tengo que presionar atrás muchas veces.

Quisiera que fuera como el instagram que a las tres veces de presionar atrás regrese a la principal, osea:

- primera presionada atrás = vista o fragment anterior
- segunda presionada atrás = vista o fragment anterior
- tercera presionada atrás = vista o fragment anterior
- cuarta presionada atrás = main activity (vista principal)
- quinta presionada atrás = cierra la aplicación.

Comment: En esta respuesta puedes econtrar información: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27414/2230

Comment: Que tal si pruebas con un Navigation Drawer Activity, en la cual puedes crear un menu desplazable en el cual colocar todas las nuevas actividades y con el cual puedas regresar al menu principal con tal solo un "Boton atras",
Te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaría tu menu.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubLJU.png

Comment: Intenta con esto en tu activity principal (la última antes de que salga de la app) @Override public void onBackPressed() { DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); //Si el menu esta abierto lo cerramos if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) { drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); return; } //Si hay algun fragmento pendiente volvemos atras if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) { //Recuperamos el ultimo titulo setTitle(tituloUltimoItemSeleccionado); super.onBackPressed(); return; } //Si no cumple con los anteriores recien evaluamos

Comment: Cuando pasas de una actividad **A** a otra actividad **B**, si no cerraste la actividad **A**, al pulsar "botón Back" vuelves a ella automáticamente, sin tener que programar nada. Es decir: Si te mueves en las actividades Principal, vas a A, B, C. cada click en botón Atrás, te moverás de C, B, A, Principal, Salir.